# How do you set up a camera in Sprite-Kit properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay, so I wanted to implement a camera in my game and on this other post I saw how to do it. (Basically what I want to achieve is that whenever my player reaches a certain height the camera moves up)

So this is the

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {

SKSpriteNode *hero = self.player;

int cameraEdge = self.player.size.height * 3;
if(hero && self.isPaused == NO)
{
    CGPoint heroPosition = hero.position;
    CGPoint worldPosition;

    worldPosition.x = 0;

    CGFloat yCoordinate = worldPosition.y + heroPosition.y;


    if ( yCoordinate < cameraEdge && heroPosition.y > -200){
        NSLog(@"Waddap bud");
        worldPosition.y = worldPosition.y  - yCoordinate + cameraEdge;
        self.worldMovedForUpdate = YES;

    }else {

        worldPosition.y = self.frame.size.height/2;
    }

    if(yCoordinate > (self.frame.size.height - cameraEdge) && heroPosition.y < 2000)
    {
        worldPosition.y = worldPosition.y + (self.frame.size.height - yCoordinate) - cameraEdge;
        self.worldMovedForUpdate = YES;

    }
    self.world.position = worldPosition;

}
}
```

Since I didn't think of this code myself I don't fully understand what is going on, but it does work. Just not the way I want it to. When the player reaches a certain y-level the camera suddenly starts following the player and the point where the switching between camera movement and no camera movement is happens when the player jumps a lot which causes very glitchy camera movement. I get this is kind of confusing but I can't think of a better way to explain it.

Can somebody please try to explain this code in detail (I can read the code, I just don't get it) and if anyone has a solution (given that you understand the problem ;P) please don't hesitate to inform me

Thanks a lot

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about the code?

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble understanding how the camera follows the `heroPosition`. Here is a good tutorial on scrolling platform games that should better help you understand how to implement this logic: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make a camera follow your player add these simple lines of code:

```
int cameraEdge = 100;

if (self.player.position.y > cameraEdge) {
worldPosition.y = cameraEdge - self.player.position.y;

}
self.world.position = worldPosition;
```

What this does: Whenever your player's y-position is higher than 100 (or whatever you set it to) the world's position starts following the player. I've tested it and it works perfectly.